# How to create a header that will apply to every request in the SwaggerUI for ASP NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to find a way to apply a header for every request to an ASP NET Core application using Swagger UI. The thing is, then I use something like IOperationFilter:

```
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
        {
            Name = "VeryImportantHeader",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Required = true,
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema
            {
                Type = "String"
            }
        });
    }
```

It adds a placeholder, which you should **manually fill for every request**, and that's kinda irritating, especially if you need to test lots of queries.

Is there a way to add a header, that will be applied to every request automatically?
For example, you can do that for the authorization, using **AddSecurityDefinition**:
[single header placeholder example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfs8W.jpg)

Comment: Have you injected it into startup with `services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
 
        config.OperationFilter<MyHeaderFilter>();
    });`

Comment: Sure, and that does the thing I've described above - it adds a header placeholder to every request (good), and you should fill it manually every time you want to run another request (not good). I was asking about a single placeholder for the whole swagger page, which will add a header to any request automatically after being filled once.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for solution and After some search i couldn't found anything.So eventually i found a solution myself. It's probably too late for you but i put the solution here for others like me .

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter:IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Security ??= new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();

        var tenantId = new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Tenant-Id" } };
        var userId = new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "User-Id" } };
        operation.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            [tenantId] = new List<string>(),
            [userId] = new List<string>()
        });
    }
}
```

after creating this class. On Startup

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Tenant-Id", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Tenant-Id",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Tenant Id",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.AddSecurityDefinition("User-Id", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "User-Id",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "User Id",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
});
```

Swagger UI Result :

[image]

[image]

request log :

[image]